# Prep line in rpm spec causes duplicate directory inside rpm

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have this spec file for my open source shell scripting sdk https://github.com/icasimpan/shcf/blob/packagebuilds/packagebuilds/rpm/shcf.spec

I build it as follows:

```
rpmbuild --target noarch -bb shcf.spec
```

Now, this builds fine, however, the output rpm's content has duplicated path "shcf/shcf", like:

```
/opt/icasimpan/shcf/shcf/***
```

This is the prep area

```
%prep
echo "BUILDROOT = $RPM_BUILD_ROOT"
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/icasimpan/shcf

cd $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/icasimpan/shcf
git clone --branch 0.3.1 https://github.com/icasimpan/shcf.git

exit
```

At first sight, it's obviously due to the clone done to "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/icasimpan/shcf". However, if I modify the clone line to say

```
git clone --branch 0.3.1 https://github.com/icasimpan/shcf.git .
```

rpm build will fail due to unpackaged files.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the objective? Are the final files in `git` or do you need to actually build anything?

Comment: Hi @AaronD.Marasco, yes I would want to produce a build. As mentioned, it builds fine, only that when listing the rpm content, the path to where it would be installed has duplicate directory. E.g. try to "rpm qlp shcf.rpm" and path inside to one of the files "/opt/icasimpan/shcf/shcf/core/bin/shcf_cli". I'd like to remove the duplicated "shcf".